# How can I separate real and imaginary parts of an equation using Sympy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I am currently writing a Python script to perform the kinematic analysis of a four-bar linkage.

A four bar linkage can be mathematically expressed as a vector loop equation:

```
a\*e^(j\*theta1) + b\*e^(j\*theta2) + c\*e^(j\*theta3) + d\*e^(j\*theta4) = 0
```

where:

- `a` is the length of the driving link and `theta1` is the angular displacement of the driving link
- `b` is the length of the coupler link and `theta2` is the angular displacement of the coupler link
- `c` is the length of the output link and `theta3` is the angular displacement of the output link
- `d` is the length of the base link and `theta4` is the angular displacement of the base link

Here, the values of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `theta4` are known, while `theta1` acts as the input variable. Thus, `theta2` and `theta3` are functions of `theta1`.

For the first part of the script, I want sympy to do the following:

- Rewrite the equation to its trigonometric form
- Separate the real and imaginary parts of the equations

The current code I have is as follows:

```
from sympy import *

a, b, c, d, theta1, theta4 = symbols("a b c d theta1 theta4", real=True)
theta2 = Function("theta2")(theta1)
theta3 = Function("theta3")(theta1)

vector_loop = a*exp(I*theta1) + b*exp(I*theta2) + c*exp(I*theta3) + d*exp(I*theta4)
vector_loop_trig = vector_loop.rewrite(cos).expand()
vector_loop_real = re(vector_loop_trig)
vector_loop_im = im(vector_loop_trig)
```

The output I get from the code is:

*Real part:*

```
a⋅cos(θ₁) - b⋅cos(re(θ₂(θ₁)))⋅sinh(im(θ₂(θ₁))) + b⋅cos(re(θ₂(θ₁)))⋅cosh(im(θ₂(θ₁))) - c⋅cos(re(θ₃(θ₁)))⋅sinh(im(θ₃(θ₁))) + c⋅cos(re(θ₃(θ₁)))⋅cosh(im(θ₃(θ₁))) + d⋅cos(θ₄)
```

*Imaginary part:*

```
a⋅sin(θ₁) - b⋅sin(re(θ₂(θ₁)))⋅sinh(im(θ₂(θ₁))) + b⋅sin(re(θ₂(θ₁)))⋅cosh(im(θ₂(θ₁))) - c⋅sin(re(θ₃(θ₁)))⋅sinh(im(θ₃(θ₁))) + c⋅sin(re(θ₃(θ₁)))⋅cosh(im(θ₃(θ₁))) + d⋅sin(θ₄)
```

However, the output I should be getting is:

*Real part:*

```
a⋅cos(θ₁) + b⋅cos(θ₂) + c⋅cos(θ₃) + d⋅cos(θ₄)
```

*Imaginary part:*

```
a⋅sin(θ₁) + b⋅sin(θ₂) + c⋅sin(θ₃) + d⋅sin(θ₄)
```

How can I fix my code to get the correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare theta2 and theta3 as real:

```
theta2 = Function("theta2", real=True)(theta1)
theta3 = Function("theta3", real=True)(theta1)
```